# onBackPress() is not working when app comes to foreground from background

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-videoview, onbackpressed

I have a videoView in my activity. onBackPress() is not working when app comes to foreground from background and also when i lock my phone and unlock it because of videoView.seekTo(1). How do we solve it

Below is my code. Please help

```
public class VideoPreviewActivity extends implements View.OnClickListener  {

    TextView tv_response;
    ImageView iv_video_preview;
    VideoView videoView;
    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "InlinedApi"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_preview);
        processIntent(getIntent());
    }


    public void processIntent(Intent intent) {
        int is_doc_context = intent.getIntExtra(IS_DOC_CONTEXT, 2);
        if (is_doc_context == 1) {

            final MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
            mc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
            mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
            final Uri video = Uri.parse(videoFileString);
            videoView.setMediaController(mc);
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);
            videoView.seekTo( 1 );

            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                }
            });
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        videoView.seekTo( 1 );
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        if (videoView.isPlaying()){
            videoView.stopPlayback();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        LibUtils.onBackButtonClick(VideoPreviewActivity.this);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any information.

Comment: Provide `LibUtils.onBackButtonClick` code.

Comment: That is custom alert dialog

Comment: remove videoView.seekTo( 1 ); from the onResume() to set the seek position setting behaviour

Comment: @PraveenSP then how can i show thumbNail for videoView. Because black screen is appearing on VideoView when the app comes to  foreground from background

Comment: Do one thing save the seekpos in onPause() and onResume() seek the position to saved pos .. Hope you got What I am trying to convey here...

Comment: @PraveenSP still its not working

Comment: can you update the code with what you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

call super.onBackPressed() inside in your override onBackPressed() method.

Comment: I have tried this one. but not working. the issue is due to videoView,seekTo(1) in onResume

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call `findViewById` for `videoView`.

1) Make sure that in your `xml` of `videoView` you add an `id`:

```
<VideoView 
android:id="@+id/video_view"
android:layout_height="......"
android:layout_width="......." />
```

2) Do this in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_preview);
    processIntent(getIntent());

    //here find the video view
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
}
```

3) One more thing in your `onBackPressed()`:

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        LibUtils.onBackButtonClick(VideoPreviewActivity.this);
        //add this
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```